# Data Structure Interview Question

Tags: data-structures

I was asked the following Question:
How would you store the data given below(which data structure would u pick):

```
A-1-2-3-4-5-6

|

B-7-8-9-10-11

|

C-12-14-15-16-17
```

My ans:
Since this looks like a bunch of lists with its head nodes linked together.
Use two node types one id the regular node type with the following definition:

```
Struct node1
{
int val;
struct node*next;
};
// to store the numerical part of the data

struct node2
{
 int val;
struct node *down;
struct node* next;
};
//this is the heads of each list.. for the alphabet part of the question.
```

The Interviewer's reaction:
Is this the best data structure u can think of .
How abt in terms of traversal  and memory needed for each node?

My answer to that:
We can traverse better if we create some sort of hash table.

My question to you comrades:
Can we do a better job ?? Is there a better way to store this type of data?

we assume that the data is all numbers (even the ones at each head node) and non serial with repetitions possible . What would be the right answer ?
Looking for answers in C/C++

Comment: It's a dumb question, in that not enough information is given to reach the "right" answer.  My answer is String, as you've told me nothing about what the data is or how it is used or how it might be modified.  You want to find 15 Quickly?  Here it is --> 15. O(1) lookup.

Comment: If the interviewer was serious about getting a useful answer, they were probably expecting you to ask questions regarding the nature of the data, such as the context it's used in, where on the memory / CPU performance tradeoff it should lie, etc.

Comment: You don't actually specify anywhere what language/language family this should be implemented in. My answers would be very different for C, C++, Scala, and Perl. :)

Comment: @Erik: When i suggested the answer above, they told me that i am wont be able to traverse the list easily. So I think any node 's value can be changed at any point.

Suppose I need to change the nodes with the value 6 to 999. I should be able to do it fast.
So we are looking for fast traversal than memory tradeoff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first question I would ask is about the data.  It **appears** to be a simple case of where to break a series of continuous numbers.  Given that I would just store the break points.  These types of questions are designed to test your ability to ask questions and drill down into the underlying issue.

Comment: @Craig:  Assume the worst abt the data .... the numbers need not be serial  and can have repetitions... The interviwer dint specify its only for this type of data ... This is the example i put up so that I can frame the question easily ...

Comment: That's the point.  He (She?) was trying to get a feel for your ASSUMTIONS.  Never assume!  It is more true of client requirements than anything else.  Your assumtions are ALWAYS wrong. :)

Comment: @Craig: will keep this in mind for the future questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that this question was aimed at getting thoughts from you about the data structure.

If it is really only a char and 6 integers for each node, you wouldn't need to store two lists. Also, how it is going to be used would be important to take into consideration. Maybe even a char and a numeric range would suffice, this depends on what the data really is.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you could use a dictionary of string/int array:

```
Dictionary<string,int[]>
```

Answer (score 0):

For better traversal and memory usage, you could consider using a list of variable-length-arrays (Java ArrayLists)

Answer (score 0):

If they literally mean "store range #s from N to N+x", then you can compress this down to a map from a letter to start-of-range and end-of-range tuple ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would ask how the data is going to be used.  The interviewer will either reveal what he initially withheld to see if you'd ask, or make something up.  Then I'd ask what kind of updates and how it will be updated.  It would be less likely for him to have thought this far ahead, so bonus interview points.  Otherwise make up an in-memory storage structure just complicated enough to account for all the facts, or maybe put it in a relational database.

Comment: A relational database? I hope you're kidding.

Comment: You need at least the Enterprise Edition of Oracle to store this kind of data :)

Comment: @Erik: Why not a relational database?  This is an interview situation where abundant potential answers should be provided by the problem solver.  Since the question is asked in isolation, you have no way of evaluating the *best* solution because you don't have enough information.  So, yes, provide a menu of options as an answer.

Comment: I think if you'd poke around with the initial questions as you mention, you would get bonus points, but ending on a 'maybe put it in a relational database', you'd undo all the bonus points and end up with "bonuspoints=-bonuspoints".

Answer (score 0):

I would say, in a simpler way possible, that you should use a list.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

B = [7,8,9,10,11]

C = [12,14,15,16,17]
```